# Swashbuckle OperationFilter to Add Parameter of Type Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, openapi, swashbuckle

I have a C# object

```cs
public class MyObject
{
 public int property1 { get; set; }
 public string property2 { get; set; }
 public string property3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a parameter of type object that has the schema of `MyObject`.

```cs
public class MyFilter : IOperationFilter
{
 public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
 {
   operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
   {
    Name = "MyParameter",
    Description = "MyDescription"
    In = ParameterLocation.Header
    Required = true,
    Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
    {
     Type = "object",
     Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>()
     {
       // MyObject
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Does Swashbuckle provide any methods that can automatically generate the properties with the schema of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer.

```cs
public class MyFilter : IOperationFilter
{
 public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
 {
   var myObjectSchema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(MyObject), context.SchemaRepository);
   operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
   {
    Name = "MyParameter",
    Description = "MyDescription"
    In = ParameterLocation.Header
    Required = true,
    Schema = myObjectSchema
   }
  }
}
```